# Streaming in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know the good practice if I'm streaming data and want to have access to whole data after streaming;

I'm streaming like this:

```
    res._oldWrite = res.write;
    res.write = function (chunk, encoding, cb) {
        var decoded = chunk.toString(encoding);
        write.write(new Buffer(decoded, encoding), encoding, cb);
        return res._oldWrite.call(res, new Buffer(decoded, encoding), encoding, cb);
    }
```

Now that I want to access to my data I did something like:

```
    res._oldWrite = res.write;
    var jsonData = '';
    res.write = function (chunk, encoding, cb) {
        var decoded = chunk.toString(encoding);
        jsonData += decoded;
        write.write(new Buffer(decoded, encoding), encoding, cb);
        return res._oldWrite.call(res, new Buffer(decoded, encoding), encoding, cb);
    }

    res.on('finish', function(){
        // Now I can have access to jsopnData but it is gross ; what is the right way?
    })
```

But isn't there any better way to do it?

Comment: So you're streaming data to a writeable stream and want to access that data? Why don't you just pipe to another stream in your custom stream? Then you can just add a lister to the second stream to get the data.

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you mean, can you show me your solution in my code...

Comment: You should **read from the stream**, not intercept `.write()` calls on it!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks but could you please elaborate it with showing your solution in my code so I can have a better understandg Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure I understand your question @Web Developer, but since you asked for code, below is all that I meant.

Note that there are probably <strike>other</strike> shorter ways of doing the same thing (but I'm not sure what you mean by "access whole data after streaming" --- store in memory? all at once? etc):

```
var dataStream = require('stream').Writable();
//I'm assuming the "real processing" is saving to a file
var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.txt');
var masterStream = require('stream').Writeable();

masterStream._write = function (chunk, enc, next) {

  dataStream.write(chunk);
  fileStream.write(chunk);
  next();
};

//if you now write to master stream, you get values in both dataStream and fileStream
//you can now listen to dataStream and "have access to the data"
```